# Continuity of function $p$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $p$ :$\mathbb {R}^2$ to $\mathbb {R}$ with $p(x,y)$ = $x$ + $y$. Prove that $p$ is continuous.

My attempt was that since $p$ is the sum of two continuous projections then it is continuous it self, but I cant help but feel that something is missing from the proof. Can anyone confirm or maybe chime in with some insight?
Any help is much appreciated as always

Comment: What definition of continuity are you using? What theorems to prove continuity do you have?

Comment: The definition that given an open set from the domain the pre-image of that set is also an open set

Comment: If you're using the topological definition then you'll need to consider the preimage of open intervals of the form $(a,b)$. Start by graphing the boundary, which is $x+y=a$ and $x+y=b$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then figuring out where the values that satisfy $x+y \in (a,b)$ are in relation to their boundary. From there, prove the set you've isolated is open. Finally consider what happens when you have two disjoint intervals such as $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ with $b<c$.

Comment: Your proof isn’t sufficient since you need that addition is continuous to sum the two continuous projections, which is basically what the question is asking in the first place.

Comment: Yes, how do I prove that addition is continuous?

Comment: @GeorgeRevingston addition is like, really continuous in this situation. I have given you a proof of that fact below, since Lipshcitz continuity implies continuity.

Comment: I am not allowed to use this condition, I should do it only with open sets. Thank you for taking the time however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that $p$ is the sum of two projection maps which are continuous, it is enough to show that $+: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. For that we will show that pre-image of any basic open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $(a,b)$ be any basic open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{align}
(+)^{-1}((a,b))&=\{(x,y): x+y \in (a,b)\} \\
&=\{(x,y): a<x+y<b\} \\
&=\{(x,y): x+y>a\} \cap \{(x,y):x+y <b\} 
\end{align}
Take any point $(\alpha, \beta) \in \{(x,y): x+y>a\}$. Then $\alpha + \beta >a$, there exists $\epsilon >0$  such that $\alpha + \beta -\epsilon >a$. We have $(\alpha, \beta) \in \left(\alpha-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \times \left(\beta-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \beta+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \subseteq \{(x,y): x+y>a\}$. Since $\left(\alpha-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \times \left(\beta-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \beta+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right)$ is a basic open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can say that $\{(x,y): x+y>a\}$ is a neighborhood of each of its points and so it's open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Similarly, $(\alpha, \beta) \in \{(x,y): x+y<b\}$. Then $\alpha + \beta <b$, there exists $\epsilon >0$  such that $\alpha + \beta + \epsilon <b$. We have $(\alpha, \beta) \in \left(\alpha-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \times \left(\beta-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \beta+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \subseteq \{(x,y): x+y<b\}$. Since $\left(\alpha-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \times \left(\beta-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \beta+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right)$ is a basic open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can say that $\{(x,y): x+y<b\}$ is a neighborhood of each of its points and so it's open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Intersection of finitely many open sets is open. Thus  '$+$'  is continuous.

Comment: Thank you, I actually figured out by myself following this method. Appreciate the help

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Set $K=2$. Let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Notice that $|x_1-x_2|,|y_1-y_2|\leq\sqrt{|x_1-x_2|^2+|y_1-y_2|^2}$ which implies  $$|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|\leq K\sqrt{|x_1-x_2|^2+|y_1-y_2|^2} $$
Then we have
$$\begin{align*}
|p(x_1,y_1)-p(x_2,y_2)|
&=|x_1+y_1-(x_2+y_2)|\\
&=|(x_1-x_2)+(y_1-y_2)|\\
&\leq|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|\\
&\leq K\sqrt{|x_1-x_2|^2+|y_1-y_2|^2}
\end{align*}$$
thus $p$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 0):

Running with @CyclotomicField's hint, it's easy to see that for a basic open set $(a,b)\subset\mathbb R $, we get that $p^{-1}((a,b)) $ is an open rectangular strip between the two lines $x+y=a $ and $x+y=b $ in $\mathbb R^2$.  Hence open.   Hence  $p $ is continuous.